# C++ Function expects size_t parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters, binary-search, size-t

I'm designing a C++ binary search method that takes in an array of 10 integers and an integer to search for. I designed the main method to take in the array from a command-line argument and prompt the user for an integer to search for. The addresses of both are passed in to the bsearch method (because passing them in directly doesn't seem to work), which then iterates through the array and searches for the supplied target. The code for my bsearch method is posted below:

```
void bsearch(int array[10], int key)        {
    int candidate;
    int min = 0;
    int max = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    bool found = false;

    while(!found)   {       //Begin iterative loop
            if(max<min)
                    break; //cout << key << " not found" << endl;   //Only executes after searching entire array
            for(int i=min;i<max;i++)        {
                    cout << array[i] << " ";        //Prints out current 
            }                                       //section being searched
            cout << endl;
            candidate = array[(max+min)/2];         //Check middle element
            if(candidate == key)    {
                    found = true;                   //Target located
            }
            else if(candidate>key)  {
                    max = ((max+min)/2)-1;          //Search lower portion
            }
            else if(candidate<key)  {
                    min = ((max+min)/2)+1;          //Search upper portion
            }
    }
    if(found)
            cout << key << " found at index " << (max+min)/2 << endl;       //Report target location
    else
            cout << key << " not found" << endl;    //Report target not found

}
```

and in the main method

```
    int target;
    int searchArray[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)   {
            searchArray[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);
    }
    cout << "Enter search query(one integer): ";
    cin >> target;
    bsearch(&searchArray, &target); //Problem is here
```

Problem is, whenever I try to compile this code, I get the error: "too few arguments to function ‘void* bsearch(const void*, const void*, size_t, size_t, __compar_fn_t)’"

What's with the additional three parameters? I didn't define them in the method, so why does it want me to supply them? Is the method trying to compare the two parameters or something?

Comment: There's a [`std::bsearch()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/bsearch) function in the standard library. And you're passing your arguments incorrectly.

Comment: `int max = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);` This is wrong. Try printing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bsearch(&searchArray, &target)` does not match the signature for your `bsearch(int[], int key)`. The first two arguments, however, do match the signature of [`std::bsearch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/bsearch), which you, likely and inadvertently, introduced into the namespace through:

```
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: That's quite a surprise, I didn't expect there to be a library function by that name. Thanks a lot! Also, I realize that the parameters of the wrong type the way I passed them in, but I actually did so in order to appease the compiler. I'll just have to rename the method and change back the parameters, then.

Comment: This is a (yet another) good example of why putting this: `using namespace std;` in your code is *always* a bad thing.  Even if your program is 3 lines.